# generated.java file location for Apache spark

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I am getting below error :

```
ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 739, Column 34: A method named "toString" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 739, Column 34: A method named "toString" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
```

Where can I find this `'generated.java'` file?

**I am using one master and 3 worker nodes.**

**SPARK version : 2.3.0**

Comment: Possible spark bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19984

Comment: @shanmuga There is no mention of location of generated.java file. My question is where can i check genarated.java file contents.

Comment: There's probably something in your code that it does not like. Can you show a bit of your code / data?

Comment: @jgp generated.java file is not part of my code , I cant share the code because of proprietary issues. Thats why I wanted to understand the location of generated file so that I can debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump it to stdout by calling:

```
dataset.queryExecution().debug().codegen();
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55350403/612704